# Check if any item in raw data is null in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

Is there a way in T-SQL to check if any element in group raw data is null and if so - not to return such a group? I was looking for a solution in SELECT as well as HAVING clause.

Neither All() nor Any() work in SELECT clause. In HAVING I'm not able to filter, because there is no such a value available.

Code example:

```
SELECT fl.Id, fl.Number, ALL(sr.MP_Id IS NOT NULL) <--- ALL does not work
FROM NumberOfChildrenCTE AS noc
    INNER JOIN [DDF].[dbo].[FL] AS fl ON noc.FLId = fl.Id
    INNER JOIN [DDF].[dbo].[FM] AS fm ON fl.Id = fm.FLId AND fm.IsActive = 1 
AND fm.IsFinished = 1
    INNER JOIN [DDF].[dbo].[S] AS s ON fm.Id = s.Id AND s.IsFinished = 1
    INNER JOIN [DDF].[dbo].[SR] AS sr ON s.Id = sr.St_Id
GROUP BY fl.Id, fl.Number
HAVING ALL(sr.MP_Id IS NOT NULL) <--- ALL does not work either
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do using `COUNT()` to check.  If none are `NULL`, then this is true:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(sr.MP_Id)
```